# Launch mobile application after installation with additional parameters from the initial "application launch" URL

Tags: android, ios, mobile, deep-linking

I am trying to find the best solution for this use case scenario and maybe somebody from here can help me with this.

With **deep-linking**, there is the possibility to carry over some additional data information as a part of the URL, which may get "inserted/injected" into the mobile application during launching time.

But the fun part comes in a use case scenario in which the actual mobile application, which should be open by URL, has not been installed, yet.

The question is, **how do you re-initiate the URL opening** phase after the end-user finishes the "mobile application installation" phase from the application store, first? Or is there any better solution for this (which works for iOS as well as for Android)?

My understanding is that, after installation is done, additional data coming as a part of the URL get lost.

Thank you in advance. M.

Answer (score 0):

Installation tracking on iOS is not as easy as on android.
You need to use third-party tools to track installs on both android and iOS.
Adjust and Appsflyer can help you.
Basically they are using fingerprint method to recognize user.